# Using photo laser paper on laser monochrome printer

Tags: printing, printer, paper

I am interested to know if there is any restriction of using a Photo laser matte type of paper e.g.220gr/m2, printing a text/vector shapes project in black and white using a (SL-M2625, 4800x600dpi) monochrome laser printer.

Trying to choose the right top of paper, I have some concerns because reading the printer manual, I can't find Photo paper as accepted media, instead I've found this message:

*Make sure not to use the inkjet photo paper with this machine. It could cause damage to the machine.*

So.. Inkjet no, but laser photo paper, yes(?). Also, I've found different type of photo paper on the market (matte even glossy or high glossy) that are sold as being compatible with *all* laser printers. 
I have to mention that the above question it's not about the weight, 220gr/m2 or a lower value is accepted by this printer model.
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you should not use inkjet photo paper is that such paper is usually coated with clay or some other absorbent material. This coating can come off and leave a residue on the laser drum and/or heat fuser.

Inkjets spray ink and have little-to no actual paper contact. Laser printers use lasers to induce a charge on a drum which lifts up charged plastic dust (toner), deposits the toner on the paper, and heats the toner to melt or vaporize, adhering it to the paper. This process can get fouled up pretty easily by e.g. clay dust and lint. If you paper is rated for laser printers, and you trust the labeling, presumably you can use it.

Note that some printers cannot sufficiently heat the paper if it is too thick, and/or you have a long run. I have seen thick papers work OK in small batches, but the fuser loses too much heat in a longer print run. If the toner is dusting or lifting off the final product, this may also be leaving deposits on the drum(s).

A lot of toner cartridges have both drums in the package so that when you change the toner, you change the drums so this helps limit residue problems.